# If an object's acceleration is zero, can its velocity be non zero?

Tags: acceleration, velocity

Question:

> > If an object's acceleration is zero, can it's velocity be non-zero? Explain by giving an example.

My Attempt:

This doesn't make any sense at all. Via my teacher's solution she said "A Person walking at a steady pace along a straight sidewalk"  $a = 0$ so $\therefore$ velocity is **constant** .. Well that may be the case, but I don't understand how my teacher saying "velocity is constant" answers the question at all?? The question asked if **velocity** can be a **NON ZERO**, and $0$ is considered a **constant** so what my teacher is saying is not really making any sense to me at all. What is an example where object's accelerration is 0 but it's $V_i$ or $V_f$ (velocity is a nonzero).. Wouldn't this be like idk, a ball that was thrown in space on the moon with a $v_i = 2m/s$ with a acceleration of 0? Would that be suitable?

Comment: I don't understand. Your teacher's example is exactly an example of constant velocity that is non-zero. I mean, the person is walking, so how could their velocity be zero? Are you mixing up "velocity" with "change in velocity"? Because if acceleration is constant, the former can be non-zero, but the latter must be zero.

Comment: Yes more negative downvotes from the insane Physicists who have NO time for simple questions from us simpletons!

Comment: Should say for the rules for this website: "Poster must know the answer to his question before he posts it! Otherwise the poster will receive downvotes and people saying "BEGAST! What is wrong with you simpleton! How do you not know1?!" "

Comment: @Shammy:  This site uses upvoting/downvoting as a way of improving content. It's subjective of course but questions/answers deemed of better quality will benefit from it. I didn't vote on this one but am not surprised some found it a low quality question.

Comment: You've gotten downvotes (not just from physicists, I would imagine) because people think that this is a poor question for one reason or another. I can see this in part (though I didn't vote), because your attempt was not yours at all, but someone else's. That said, as the issue is conceptual, the typical homework-show-your-effort rationale might not be applicable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't *entirely* disagree with the downvotes. With a little more thought, you could've come up with this yourself. The fact that the answer is in *any* introductory physics textbook means that this question is not all that useful *for the Physics.SE community*. Consider that you could've just asked your instructor this question, and she would have been able to answer it quickly. I don't want to discourage you from asking questions, but note for instance that your "heavy crate" problem clearly violated the homework policy, which is why it was downvoted.

Comment: Zero is a constant, but zero is not the _only_ constant.

Comment: @HDE226868 You have no clue what you're talking about. I'm involved in the Stack Overflow exchange and the Mathematics Exchange, something you physicists don't know too much about (math) LOL, but was a good effort m8.

Comment: @Shammy You need to have a better attitude about this. Physics Stack Exchange is not a homework help site. You need to show effort about what you're asking about. You haven't done so; hence the downvotes. What I'm saying is not trolling, as you have claimed, but a genuine attempt to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed. Derivative of velocity with respect to time is acceleration.That means if accelerations is zero, velocity must be constant. Now that constant could be anything like it could be 5 m/s .Also if the velocity is 0(which is itself a constant) also indicates that acceleration is zero.

Comment: Awesome! Finally an answer instead of people trolling! Thanks so much! There is hope for Physics exchange!